# How to use dataReceived in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I have implemented a server program using Twisted. I am using `basic.lineReceiver` with the method `dataReceived` to receive data from multiple clients. Also, I am using `protocol.ServerFactory` to keep track of connected clients. The server sends some commands to each connected client. Based on the response that the server gets from each client, it (the server) should perform some tasks. Thus, the best solution that came to my mind was to create a buffer for received messages as a python list, and each time that the functions at server side want to know the response from a client, they access the last element of the buffer list (of that client). 
This approach has turned out to be unreliable. The first issue is that since TCP streaming is used, sometimes messages merge (I can use a delimiter for this). Second, the received messages are sometimes not in their appropriate sequence. Third, the networking communication seems to be too slow, as when the server initially tries to access the last element of the buffered list, the list is empty (this shows that the last messages on the buffer might not be the response to the last sent commands). 
Could you tell me what is the best parctice for using `dataReceived` or its equivalents in the above problem? thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1:** Answer- While I accept @Jean-Paul Calderone's answer since I certainly learned from it, I would like to add that in my own research of Twisted's documentation, I learned that in order to avoid delays in communications of the server, one should use `return` at the end of dataReceived() or lineReceived() functions, and this solved part of my problem. The rest, were explained in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have implemented a server program using Twisted. I am using basic.lineReceiver with the method dataReceived to receive data from multiple clients.

This is a mistake - an unfortunately common one brought on by the mistaken use of inheritance in many of Twisted's protocol implementations as the mechanism for building up more and more sophisticated behaviors.  When you use `twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver`, the `dataReceived` callback is *not for you*.  `LineReceiver.dataReceived` is an *implementation detail* of `LineReceiver`.  The callback for you is `LineReceiver.lineReceived`.  `LineReceiver.dataReceived` looks like it might be for you - it doesn't start with an underscore or anything - but it's not.  `dataReceived` is how `LineReceiver` receives information from its transport.  It is one of the public methods of `IProtocol` - the interface between a transport and the protocol interpreting the data received over that transport.  Yes, I just said "public method" there.  The trouble is it's public for the benefit of *someone else*.  This is confusing and perhaps not communicated as well as it could be.  No doubt this is why it is a [Frequently Asked Question](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith).

> This approach has turned out to be unreliable. The first issue is that since TCP streaming is used, sometimes messages merge (I can use a delimiter for this).

Use of `dataReceived` is why this happens.  `LineReceiver` already implements delimiter-based parsing for you.  That's why it's called "line" receiver - it receives lines separated by a delimiter.  If you override `lineReceived` instead of `dataReceived` then you'll be called which each line that is received, regardless of how TCP splits things up or smashes them together.

> Second, the received messages are sometimes not in their appropriate sequence.

TCP is a reliable, *ordered*, stream-oriented transport.  "Ordered" means that bytes arrive in the same order they are sent.  Put another way, when you `write("x"); write("y")` it is guaranteed that the receiver will receive "x" before they receive "y" (they may receive "x" and "y" in the same call to `recv()` but if they do, the data will definitely be "xy" and not "yx"; or they may receive the two bytes in two calls to `recv()` and if they do, the first `recv()` will definitely by "x" and the second will definitely be "y", not the other way around).

If bytes appear to be arriving in a different order than you sent them, there's probably another bug somewhere that makes it *look* like this is happening - but it actually isn't.  Your platform's TCP stack is very likely very close to bug free and in particular it probably doesn't have TCP data re-ordering bugs.  Likewise, this area of Twisted is extremely well tested and probably works correctly.  This leaves a bug in your application code or a misinterpretation of your observations.  Perhaps your code doesn't always append data to a list or perhaps the data isn't being sent in the order you expected.

Another possibility is that you are talking about the order in which data arrives across multiple separate TCP connections.  TCP is only ordered over a single connection.  If you have two connections, there are very few (if any) guarantees about the order in which data will arrive over them.

> Third, the networking communication seems to be too slow, as when the server initially tries to access the last element of the buffered list, the list is empty (this shows that the last messages on the buffer might not be the response to the last sent commands).

What defines "too slow"?  The network is as fast as the network is.  If that's not fast enough for you, find a fatter piece of copper.  It sounds like what you really mean here is that your server sometimes expects data to have arrived before that data actually arrives.  This doesn't mean the network is too slow, though, it means your server isn't properly *event driven*.  If you're inspecting a buffer and not finding the information you expected, it's because you inspected it before the occurrence of the event which informs you of the arrival of that information.  This is why Twisted has all these callback methods - `dataReceived`, `lineReceived`, `connectionLost`, etc.  When `lineReceived` is called, this is an event notification telling you that *right now* something happened which resulted in a line being available (and, for convenience, `lineReceived` takes one argument - an object representing the line which is now available).

If you have some code that is meant to run when a line has arrived, consider putting that code inside an implementation of the `lineReceived` method.  That way, when it runs (in response to a line being received), you can be 100% sure that you have a line to operate on.  You can also be sure that it will run as soon as possible (as soon as the line arrives) but no sooner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the order of received messages, if I use the python socket library at the client side, by writing socket.recv() or socket.send, can this cause the connection not to be TCP?

Comment: If you use `socket.socket()` (with no arguments) to create the socket, it's a TCP socket (and can only be used to make TCP connections).  Also, `reactor.listenTCP` creates a server that can only accept TCP connections.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I want to send the data from the syslog line by line but the lineReceived always gives me byte required str received how could i overwrite this, it works fine in dataReceived.

Comment: @Root Sounds like a problem with your string types.  Though it sounds related to this question I think you should open a new question with all of the details (http://sscce.org/) and I'm sure you'll get a good answer there.